# Code is working only in Jupyter, but the script keeps on crashing when I run it directly from the desktop

Tags: python, jupyter

First submission here, please don't be too judgemental. So I've written this piece of code to make a "guess a word" game and it works in Jupyter, though it still has some points to be improved. However, I tried to save it as a ".py" file and run it directly from my desktop, but it keeps on crashing. I tried to add some troubleshooting via "pdb", but the application still kept on crashing. Could you please help me on resolving this problem? Any other suggestions on improving the code are appreciated.

P.s.: I'm from Russia, so the game runs using Russian vocabulary, but it shouldn't affect the code... does it?

```
import random
import io
from __future__ import print_function

class Random_word():

    def __init__(self):
        self.word = self.new_word()
        self.tries = int(6)
        self.used_letters = []

    def new_word(self):
        with io.open('C:\\Users\\mi\\Documents\\Jupyter\\WordsStockRus.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            words = (f.read())
            words = words.splitlines()
            number = random.randint(0, len(words))
            word = words[number]
        self.word = list(i for i in word)

    def string(self):
        for i in self.word:
            if i not in self.used_letters:
                print('_', end=' ')
            elif i in self.used_letters:
                print(i, end=' ')

    def game_over(self):
        return set(self.word) <= set(self.used_letters) or self.tries < int(1)

    def new_game(self):
        self.used_letters.clear()
        self.new_word()
        self.tries = int(input('How many tries do you want to have?'))

Game = Random_word()
Game.new_game()
print(f'Hello, My dear friends. I\'d like to offer you to play a game of hangman
menu = str('New game / Exit')

while Game.game_over() == False:
    print(f'You have {Game.tries} tries to guess the word.')
    Game.string()
    try:
        player_input = input('Enter a letter:')
        if player_input in Game.used_letters:
            raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print('Na-ah, already used it')
    if player_input in Game.word:
        print('Good one!')
        Game.used_letters.append(player_input)
    elif player_input not in Game.word:
        print('Bad luck!')
        Game.used_letters.append(player_input)
        Game.tries -= 1
else:
    print('Game over.')
    print(Game.word)
    player_input = input(f'Please enter your choice:{menu}')
    if player_input == 'New game':
        Game.new_game()
    elif player_input == 'Exit':
        print('Thank you for the game.')
```

Comment: Check this line `print(f'Hello, My dear friends. I\'d like to offer you to play a game of hangman` - no closing quote and bracket. Also, you are using python3, no need to import print function from `__future__`.

Comment: Also, there is no need this to be f-string.

Comment: If "it keeps on crashing", could you please post the traceback?